# In this i want to find the profit can someone tell me the correct way

Tags: mysql, database

```
create table product_details(
 product_ID int primary key unique not null auto_increment,
 product_name varchar(30) not null,
 product_purchase_price int not null,
 product_sale_price int not null
);

Insert into  product_details( product_ID,product_name, product_purchase_price, product_sale_price)
values(1,"lays",20,30);
insert into  product_details( product_name, product_purchase_price, product_sale_price)
values("Choclate",30,35);
insert into  product_details( product_name, product_purchase_price, product_sale_price)
values("Coke",90,120);

select * from product_details;

select  (product_sale_price) - (product_purchase_price) As PROFIT 
from product_details
where product_id=1;
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? Output is produced and is as coded ie 10 (which is correct)

Comment: it cannot show profit in table.@P.Salmon

Comment: It does see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f3Fb8Jq5JjC3yLFmoUCUxY/0 please add your expected output to the question to clarify.

Comment: its working fine now @P.Salmon